# Why don't my udev rules work inside of a running docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, udev

I have udev rules written to create SYMLINKS when a device is connected. The rules are working fine on the host machine, but when I start a container with these same rules installed in /etc/udev/rules.d, they don't work inside my container.

I am trying to detect when an external drive is plugged in and create a corresponding symlink. /dev/sdX is created on boot of the container iff the drive was present at time of `docker run`, but it won't appear after the run command, nor will it disappear upon the drive being removed.

Here's an example rule that works just fine on the host machine:

`KERNEL=="sd?", SYMLINK+="test_%k"`

Comment: Would you please post what kind of device you'd like to handle and what your rules look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. What I've seen done on the internet is to mount the host's `/dev` inside the container:

`docker run -v=/dev:/dev` *(Note: not safe)*

But this is very dangerous and pretty much destroys the host computer by mucking with permissions (e.g. psuedo-terminals can't be spawned).

However, if **I set up a udev rule on the host machine to create devices in a unique subdirectory, like `/dev/foo/sdX`**, I can then just share `dev/foo` with my container:

**`docker run -v=/dev/foo:/dev/foo`**

Now, when I insert a drive that matches my udev rule, the host machine creates a symlink in `/dev/foo/sdX`, which is now suddenly visible to my container. When the drive is removed, `/dev/foo/sdX` also disappears.

---

The one missing feature that would be nice is the ability to trigger a script inside the container when the device is created. A udev rule can do that on the host machine, but no udev rules seem to be tripped inside the container. So manual polling it is, for now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of device you'd like to handle.

Udev in containers is mentioned in

- [How can enable udev sync successfully in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209642/how-can-enable-udev-sync-successfully-in-docker)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/n4Xtvsb4RAw
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/
- http://dummdida.tumblr.com/post/118770655240/udev-events-in-containers

Especially the latest link gives hints how to debug the situation.

You can monitor events related to udev by using:

```
$ udevadm monitor
```

And for fun you can trigger events by calling:

```
$ udevadm trigger --subsystem=net --action=change
```

The docker support for udev is obviously limited since docker is not working like a virtualization environment in all aspects.

Comment: I'm able to see events with `udevadm monitor`, but my rules don't get triggered on any of these commands.

Comment: @Wolfgang Fahl, > The docker support for udev is obviously limited.    What's limited? Do you have any idea for my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060604/why-udev-init-script-default-disable-container-support-while-in-fact-it-works)?