# Why udev init script default disable container support while in fact it works?

Tags: docker, udev

Use `docker run -idt -v /dev:/dev --privileged --name delete ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash` to new a container, and in container use `apt-get install -y udev` to install udev.

When start udev, it reports next:

```
root@0947408dab9b:~# service udev start
 * udev does not support containers, not started
```

Then, I change the init script in `/etc/init.d/udev`, comments next 2 parts:

```
1) Comments next:
#if ! ps --no-headers --format args ax | egrep -q '^\['; then
#    log_warning_msg "udev does not support containers, not started"
#    exit 0
#fi

2) Comments next:
#if [ ! -w /sys ]; then
#    log_warning_msg "udev does not support containers, not started"
#    exit 0
#fi
```

Then, re-execute `service udev start`:

```
root@0947408dab9b:/etc/init.d# service udev start
 * Starting the hotplug events dispatcher systemd-udevd  starting version 237
  [ OK ]
 * Synthesizing the initial hotplug events... [ OK ]
 * Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...  [ OK ]
```

Then, I verify the udev in container with some udev rules added, and unplug/plug some usb device, I saw it works.

So, my question is: why in udev init script disable this in container, it's really works... Possible any special scenario I'm not aware?

**UPDATE:**

Also add tests next:

**1. I add a simple rule next:**

```
root@0947408dab9b:/dev# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/100.rules
ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="thisistestfile"
```

**2. service udev restart**

**3. Unplug/Plug the usb mouse**

We could see there is a file with the name "thisistestfile" in `/dev`:

```
root@0947408dab9b:/dev# ls -alh /dev/thisistestfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 28 08:58 /dev/thisistestfile -> input/event12
```

Answer (score 4):

## Why `udev` disabled in containers, it's really works

[udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev#Operation) is a generic device manager running as a daemon on a Linux system and listening (via a netlink socket) to uevents the kernel sends out if a new device is initialized or a device is removed from the system. `udev` is now [part of](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/master/src/udev) `systemd`.

I think it is not about `udev` but controversy between `docker` and `systemd` developers. [Daniel Walsh](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/author/rhatdan/) has a good article series about this topic. I highly recommend [this one](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/) and [this one](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/). Basically, common systems usually have a init system that running as `PID 1`. Upstream `docker` says any process can run as `PID 1` in a container. This process is your application and they are recommending to run every application in a separate [container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/). The `systemd` developers believe the opposite. They say you should always run an init system as `PID` 1 in any environment. They state that `PID 1` provides services to the processes inside the container that are part of the Linux API.

Both sides are making it hard to run `systemd` in a `docker` container even though like you said `it's really works`.

If you want to learn more about the conflict here is another good [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/).

Comment: I'm not so convinced by the answer, but still upvote it just because maybe it's the truth. You mean it print `udev does not support containers` just because `udev is part of systemd`, 'systemd guys` & `docker guys` have different thought on `PID1`? So `systemd`guy chose to disable it in `/etc/init.d/udev`?If that,it's really shameful for this 2 orgs that they can't make aglined,and furthermore for `systemd guys` just disble it dispite of the truth `it could works with service udev start`.User could chose if to enable udev, but software should not do the decision for user if it really can work.

Comment: Any more direct proof related to udev & docker? You know udev really could work without systemd, systemd just a init system.

Comment: Recently i try to create images with `systemd` for ansible testing. I started searching about init system and deamon process behaviour in `docker container`. Most of the init system and deamons need `privileged` flag. But it creates [security vulnerabilities](https://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/why-running-a-privileged-container-in-docker-is-a-bad-idea/#:~:text=As%20the%20privileged%20container%20is,the%20available%20capabilities%2C%20including%20CAP_SYS_ADMIN.). Maybe `udev` is disabling itself for security reasons. But i do not know exactly.